# Комментарии пользователя

Tags: python, django, mvc, get

В проекте использую стандартный модуль **`Django`** `django.contrib.comments`, и стандартную модель пользователя: `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. Мне нужно в **`View`** получить список всех комментариев пользователя. Как это сделать? (Какой использовать запрос в `get()` и к чему этот `get()` применять)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У пользователя есть привязка по полю user с моделью Comment.
Вот пример:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)  # или user = request.user
user_comments = Comment.objects.filter(user=user).all()
```

А еще почитай [The built-in comment models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/comments/models/), там можно вытянуть и другие данные комментария.

Comment: О, супер, спасибо огромное, а если вместо `filter(user=user).all()` использовать `get(user=user)` это не будет равносильно?

Comment: Нет, так нельзя. get() возвращает одну запись, а all() возвращает список (выборку).

Можно не использовать в конце .all(), тогда Вы получите QuerySet, который в дальнейшем еще можно отфильтровать и т.п

Comment: @chernysh, и последний вопрос: как отсортировать по дате?

Comment: Comment.objects.filter(user=user)юorder_by('submit_date') - От старых к новым, и наоборот от новых к старым: Comment.objects.filter(user=user)юorder_by('-submit_date')

Comment: @chernysh, спасибо!